# Make Icon Notification javafx

Tags: notifications, icons, javafx

I would like to ask how is it possible to make a notification icon over an existing Node !
Here is a link I'm using as inspiration !
http://www.red-team-design.com/notification-bubble-css3-keyframe-animation
It would really save me if anyone could give me a help ^^

Comment: But you should to show us your effort first. Show testing demo code, at least code of css and/or animation.

Comment: I've tried using the tooltip but it turns out not good, that is why I'm asking in the first place man ^^

Comment: Also try with [PopupControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html).

Comment: How is that possible to do with popup ^^ ??

Comment: any one got an idea, perhaps ??

Comment: Can you first do an animation of bubble like as in the link you posted. Then maybe someone else will help you with popping up it on the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved The problem.
I've used the animation created by billman but not extending the StackPane this time, but by extending the Button Node, and I've set the Notification icon to be extending from the StackPane and it worked out perfectly !!

Here the way to do so:

AnimatedButton.java

```
    import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
    import javafx.util.Duration;


    public class Icons extends MenuItem {

    private final Node icon;

    private AnimationType type;

    public Icons(String text, Node icon, AnimationType type) {
        setText(text);
        setGraphic(icon);
        this.icon = icon;
        this.type = type;
        addAnimation();
    }

    private void addBlinkAnimation() {
        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(icon.opacityProperty(), 0.0);
        final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700), kv);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void addJumpAnimation() {
        final TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(200), icon);
        final double start = 0.0;
        final double end = start - 4.0;
        translateTransition.setFromY(start);
        translateTransition.setToY(end);
        translateTransition.setCycleCount(-1);
        translateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        translateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
        translateTransition.play();
    }

    public enum AnimationType {

        BLINK, JUMP, NONE;
    };

    private void addAnimation() {
        switch (type) {
            case BLINK:
                addBlinkAnimation();
                break;
            case JUMP:
                addJumpAnimation();
                break;
            case NONE:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here's the main.java

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuButton menu = new MenuButton("Bienvenue, Yassine", new ImageView(new Image("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fs-icons-ubuntu-by-franksouza-/32/google-chrome.png", 20, 20, true, true)));
        menu.setCenterShape(true);
        Icons btn = new Icons("Notification", createNotification("5"), Icons.AnimationType.JUMP);
        Icons btn2 = new Icons("Mails", createNotification("4"), Icons.AnimationType.JUMP);
        Icons btn3 = new Icons("Private Messages", createNotification("10"), Icons.AnimationType.JUMP);
        menu.getItems().addAll(btn, btn2, btn3);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("notification_icon.css").toExternalForm());
        root.getChildren().add(menu);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Node createNotification(String number) {
        StackPane p = new StackPane();
        Label lab = new Label(number);
        lab.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white");
        Circle cercle = new Circle(10, Color.rgb(200, 0, 0, .9));
        cercle.setStrokeWidth(2.0);
        cercle.setStyle("-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;");
        cercle.setSmooth(true);
        p.getChildren().addAll(cercle, lab);
        return p;
    }

}
```

and the css

```
    .label{
    -fx-font-size: 12;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-padding:5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example here:
https://www.billmann.de/post/2012/08/05/javafx-miniiconanimationbutton/